# Share a database with .NET Web Application and .NET Mobile App

Tags: .net, .net-core

Is it possible to share a database from a .net core web app and use it to build a phone app? I haven't been able to look at the phone development yet but I know I would want the same database.

Where should I start? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should be able to connect any number of application to a database, however this is not a good idea in highly concurrent senarios, and may have performance impacts. Nonetheless, if your application doesnt need to deal lots of requests you can use the same database that your mobile backend server uses with no problem